# SQL SELECT INTO query with a Join, Error "There is already an object named '*****' in the database."

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select-into

I'm currently trying to copy data from table into another by using a SELECT INTO query.
But Im receiving an error in SQL Server.

"Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 
There is already an object named 'Product' in the database."

Im still very new to sql.
This is the SQL script I've created to do the job.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT d.[PDate]
      ,d.[SDate]
      ,d.[UseDRM]
      ,d.[CreatedBy]
      ,d.[CreatedDate]
      ,d.[UpdatedBy]
      ,d.[UpdatedDate]
INTO [******].[dbo].[Product]
FROM [******].[dbo].[ProductTypeData] AS d
JOIN [******].[dbo].[Product] AS t
ON d.ProductTypeDataID = t.ProductTypeDataID
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

I have already created these column in the destination table but they are currently empty.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: SQL is a language. Given the error message, I've *guessed* you're on SQL Server and added that tag. If incorrect, please edit your tags to indicate which database product you're using.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

SELECT INTO is used to create a table based on the data you have.

As you have already created the table, you want to use INSERT INTO.

E.g.

```
INSERT INTO table2 (co1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table1
```

Comment: Yesterday I found your solution and gratefully used it. Today I did the same mistake again, wondering how I did it yesterday, I googled and came to your answer again. Would upvote it a second time! :))

Answer (score 4):

Select Into is used to create the new table.

Instead of that you can use

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table2
```